# Promise to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise

I have a node module that returns an array.
I tried to access what it returns to my original program and do some array manipulations.

```
smallArray = module(param);
bigArray.push(smallArray);
```

What i got though was `[object Promise]` as an output.

Turns out, what the node module returns is not an array but a Promise.

As you can understand, i am a beginner to promises.

Is there i can modify, either to my program, or the module itself, in order to access the data back to my original program?

Comment: [Using promises - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: A lot more context about what the module that returns the promise is, what it's doing and where we can find its code would allow people to offer a much more specific answer. As it is now, your question is **overly broad** and we can offer nothing more than any other article on how promises are used can do which you should have read before coming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your method as async, and then use await.  Much clearer then using *Promise.then*.

```
async theMethod() {
  smallArray = await module(param);
  bigArray.push(smallArray);
}
```

Now, if module returns a promise, your covered.  And if it returns a non-promise, your still covered :)

Also, you can now await your method from another method because it's return value is wrapped in a promise behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Would be nice with some more background on what module it is, but generally you need to handle the promise in some way. That means calling:

`.then(function(promise) { ...Do something when your promise is succesful here.... }`

and possibly also:

`.catch(function(promise) { ...Do something when your promise was not succesful here.... }`.

Try reading through the MDN documentation on Promises:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 2):

If the module function returns a Promise, maybe you can use `.then()` to access the result :

```
module(param).then( something => bigArray.push(something) )
```